# HTTP logs shows URLs with '\" and \"x\"=\"x' appended

Tags: security, url, webserver, exploit

I had a recent issue in my server-side code, where an unexpected http query value was coming through.  Upon inspection of the logs, I see that my URL has had the following text appended to it:

`\" and \"x\"=\"x`

Thus the normal url: `something.com/foo?test=true` has been rewritten to `something.com/foo?test=true\" and \"x\"=\"x`.

I assume this is some sort of test to see if an exploit exists on my server.  This is very difficult to Google due to the characters involved, and the only results I could come up with was a log file that also appeared to have the exact same text appended to a URL.

Anyone have any info on what this is trying to exploit?  My service is a US-only service (providing local community information), and the IP address from which this request came from is 31.177.95.9, which unsurprisingly is a Russian IP address.

Comment: It looks like they are trying to inject SQL --  Seeing if they can return a mysql error that may show table info  .. Once they see table info, (if your programming has exploitable code in it)  the attacks get more complicated as they can actually execute SQL knowing table names and fields.

Comment: To me It looks like it is a try to break out of a quoted context like sql value or html element attribute value. Maybe somebody tried, whether the web site output changes afterwards, broke html code or something similar. Often several different tries are made to find a security gap. I recommend to encode the input depending on the framework that have to process the incoming data.